# Deserializing two files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, uwp

In a new UWP app I'm trying to deserialize two XML-files previously generated. The first file is deserialized as expected. The second file isn't. The sub exits without any error at the line marked in the code.

This is my code:

```
Public Shared Async Sub DeSerializer(Folder As String)
    Dim _StorageFolder As StorageFolder = Await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Folder)
    Dim _StorageFile As StorageFile = Await _StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync("Categories.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
    Dim _Serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of SingleButton)))
    Dim _Stream As Stream = Await _StorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync

    CategoryButtons.List = _Serializer.Deserialize(_Stream)

    _Stream.Dispose()

    ' --> Execution stops at the next line
    _StorageFile = Await _StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync("Items.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
    _Stream = Await _StorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync

    ItemButtons.List = _Serializer.Deserialize(_Stream)
End Sub
```

If I change up the code so the second file is processed first, this file is loaded perfectly (and execution of the sub still stops at the line indicated). So, it doesn't seem to be a problem with the xml-files.

Any suggestion on how to get this working?

Comment: It is happening because you have **disposed** the `_Stream` instance by calling `_Stream.Dispose()` before executing it for the second file. Create a new `_Stream` instance instead if you want to call the second one. Else use [_Stream.Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) to continue using the same instance

Comment: Great! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As per o_O's comment: just change _Stream.Dispose to _Stream.Flush.